# Android ViewFlipper and ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, viewflipper, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView that is being populated dynamically and I want to use ViewFlipper to switch to a new screen with a button when an item in the first list is clicked.

I have already added an OnItemClickListener so that when I click the item in the list it will display a message.

The problem is that when I add the showNext() method in the onItemClick() method the application just crashes with NullPointerException.

I'm just looking for the flipper to make a transition from the screen with the list to the screen with the button.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    deviceListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deviceList);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    deviceListView = getListView();


    flippy = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    //flippy.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    //getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

    deviceListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {   
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            System.out.println("Before Flipper");
            flippy.showNext();
            System.out.println("After Flipper");
        }
    });


    getApplicationContext().bindService(
            new Intent(this, BrowserUpnpService.class),
            serviceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
    );
}
```

Here is the XML I am using

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <ViewFlipper
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/flipper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                <ListView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/deviceList"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </ListView>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" >
                </Button>
            </ViewFlipper>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Update:

Here is the error log I am getting:

```
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482): java.lang.NullPointerException  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at com.app.browser.BrowseActivity$3.onItemClick(BrowseActivity.java:156)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)  
07-01 12:31:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code from my main activity class

```
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BrowseActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("device")
            .setIndicator("Devices", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MediaPlayer.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("media")
            .setIndicator("Media Player", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutname);` which means that your layout is not being put onto the screen. The result is that `findViewById()` is going to return null to you. Since you are trying to call `null.showNext();` you are getting a nullPointerException on that line.

Comment: I am calling setContentView(R.layout.main); in another class and it works when I remove "flippy.showNext();"

Comment: Post the other class code. I still think that this is the error. If you have two seperate Activities the setContentView() call is not going to carry over from one to the other.

Comment: What should I be implementing if I do have two Activities?